# Replace ceiling fan with fan + light

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have an old noisy ceiling fan that I plan to replace. Can I install a ceiling fan with a light fixture regardless of the wiring, or do I need to open it up to see what I'm working with before buying the new fan?

There's only one switch that controls the ceiling fan, I'm not sure if there's wiring for a second switch in the box or not. Regardless, I don't particularly mind if there's only a single switch for the fan/light - I can always use the pull cord to turn the fan on/off.

Answer (score 1):

### I would open it up at the switch-box end if I were you

What I would do if I were in your shoes is open up the *switch box* for the switch controlling this fan to see if an extra conductor is present in the cable from the fan to the switch.  If so, then you can use a double switch to have separate wall switches for the light and fan.  If not, then you're stuck using the pull chains, a fan remote, or a specialized controller that lets you control the light and fan from a single wall device.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Only difference being, if the existing fan is switched, that your light and fan will be powered by the same switch. You can optionally use the new units pull cords to operate the fan and light kit separately.

You'll have 4 wires attached to the motor. A green ground wire, a white common wire, and a black and usually a blue wire. Twist the black and blue wires together before securely attaching to the black lead that's in the ceiling box with a wire nut. ( Black normally powers the fan while blue powers the light kit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question your new fan and light fixture will ,more than likely, come seperated in the same box.  The motor connects to the existing wires on your ceiling, once the motor is secured you assemble the rest of the fan.  The last step is connecting the electrical wires to the fan and then mounting fixture.  All the wire you need for the light comes with the fan where I'm pointing. [image]